# Capitalize filter in symfony2 Constraint Messages

Tags: symfony, filter, twig, constraints, translation

I'm new to symfony. I searched a lot especially in the symfony documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages

But I found nothing about it.
I know how to use capitalize twig filter in a twig template.
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/capitalize.html

```
{{ 'my first car'|capitalize }}
```

But is it possible to capitalize a translation in these three scenarios:

In entities annotations Constraints Messages (this example does not work, translation is not translated if I add |capitalize)

```
class Author
{
    /** 
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message = "author.name.not_blank|capitalize")
     */
    public $name;
}
```

In a form builder (this example does not work, translation is not translated if I add |capitalize)

```
->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'invalid_message' => 'user.password_confirm_mismatch|capitalize',
            'first_options'  => array('label' => 'Password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'Repeat Password'),
            'required' => false
            )
```

In a controller with the [translator service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#basic-translation). In this case it is not very important because I can use the php ucfirst function. But maybe there is another method more in line with symfony best practices.

```
//Not capitalized, any way to add twig capitalize filter in this code?
$tranlsation_test_1 = $this->get('translator')->trans('info.profile_updated_successfully',array(),null,$new_user_app_language_code);

//Capitalized but with the php ucfirst function
$tranlsation_test_2 = ucfirst($this->get('translator')->trans('info.profile_updated_successfully',array(),null,$new_user_app_language_code));
```

Many tanks for your advices.

Comment: `|capitalize` only work in twig temlate not in PHP. You are trying to capitalize only translated messages ? Why do you don't simply add a capital letter in your translation files ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That's what I thought. I use some translations sometimes capitalized and sometimes not (intagrated in the middle of another sentence for exemple). So I just wanted to know it was possible to avoid having to make 2 translations one capitalized and the other not. Now I know, I need to add a capital letter directly in my translation file. Thanks

Comment: This is something to be improved, kind of a pain to have to make both translations